# How to get user tasks from My Site task list?

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, 2013

I'm working on a solution in SharePoint 2013. It's a Web Part that is going to display the five tasks that are due next from the task list on the current users' My Site. I'm new to SharePoint and kind of lost here. If anybody has some suggestions or advice on how to achieve this I would be grateful.

Thanks!

Joakim

Comment: it's a custom webpart or xslt webpart ?

Comment: Hi! It's a custom visual Web Part

Comment: See my solution at
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80745/retrieve-users-tasks-from-mysites-using-server-object-model

Answer (score 1):

Found it: The tasks in a User profile seem to be stored in a special list called 'WmaAggregatorList_User'. It's not even stored as a task contenttype.

I have created a blog entry on this: http://blog.amtopm.be/2013/02/22/getting-personal-tasks-from-the-user-profile/

See also. Stack exchange post:
[Get Task items from User Profile?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/get-task-items-from-user-profile)

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical your SharePoint Site Collection and the My-Sites Site Collection is at the same Level. It's not easy to get cross-site-collection information in a Webpart.

https://DemoSP.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Homepage.aspx (normal SP 2013)

https://DemoSP-my.sharepoint.com/default.aspx         (MySite Site Collection)

You may need to hard-code the my-Site Url and try to get information from the Task-list.

You can use something like this to get your My-Site Web-Objekt

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("https://DemoSP-my.sharepoint.com/"))
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.RootWeb)
    {
         //find your list, get infos...
    }
}
```

Hope its a little help.

Comment: The tasks in the User Profile (my sites) are not stored in a standard task list. I already looped through all the lists stored in those sites. Seems that the User Profiles have something special going on.