# Get Task items from User Profile?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How are the tasks stored in the User Profile (MySite)?

Getting items (tasks) from a standard list in SharePoint is no problem. But the tasks created in the User Profile site of a user seem to be stored differently. I can not find a list or location where those 'private' tasks are stored.

Anybody an idea where to look for these?

Regards,
Wout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: The tasks in a User profile seem to be stored in a special list called 'WmaAggregatorList_User'. It's not even stored as a task contenttype.

I have created a blog entry on this:
http://blog.amtopm.be/2013/02/22/getting-personal-tasks-from-the-user-profile/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure tasks are always stored in a task list no matter who or what they are created for, could it be they are in the list but cannot be seen in your current view?

S

Answer (score 0):

as I know, users content is stored in personal sites. Each user can work with own site collection, which can contain many webs. This site collection by default contains document libraries and as I guess task lists. You can access this content as usually with SharePoint object API, just you need to work with specific site collection for specific user.