# SP 2013 My Site - Tasks - Page can't be displayed

Tags: my-site, sharepoint-server, tasks

On a SP 2013 My Site on 2 different environments we see the same behavior, that the page **/personal/useraccountname/AllTasks.aspx** could not be found.

Has anybody come across this issue before or do you know how to troubleshoot it ?

My troubleshooting effort so far:

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/60255/10170) answer suggests the actual tasks are held in the **WmaAggregatorList_User** list,  but so far I couldn't reach it through these links:

- /personal/useraccountname/Lists/WmaAggregatorList_User
- /personal/useraccountname/WmaAggregatorList_User

EDIT:

We are indeed missing the **WmaAggregatorList_User** on our mysite's. I have been able to retrieve it on a local machine.

EDIT2:

Some more info has surfaced after more troubleshooting.

- We have checked all necessary permissions and have tried changing the accounts of MySite host, User Profile Service, Work Management Service all to the same and any of the following:

  - Farm Account
  - Same Services managed account
  - Other services managed account
  - None of them work
- The error is limited to pages with the **PersonalSpaceRedirect** UserControl, any layouts pages / libraries in the site are accessible.
- The Feature adding this functionality is called **MyTasksDashboard**. You can look in the hive at the files and you will see it registering FeatureStaplers to the MySite feature.
- Browsing to /personal/useraccountname/alltasks.aspx of the logged in user gives a "PageNotFound" because there UserControl on the page **PersonalSpaceRedirect** gives a ThreadAbortException in RedirectToGlobalPrivatePage().
- There is some logic that decides where to redirect to in this UserControl, you can route the logic to another exit by appending **?Public=0&PublicUrl=something** to /personal/useraccountname/alltasks.aspx and browse to another user's personal site with the farm account and suddenly the page does display, although there's not tasks and it says **Last updated at 1/1/1901 12:00 AM**, which is another issue I think.
- The User Profile Guid in the web's property bag is the correct User Profile guid for the account.

Answer (score 1):

Has the Work Management Service been properly provisioned? Also can you check through designer or [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) if the list is indeed missing? If it is then probably the Work Management Service has not been properly started and configured.

Please see the following article on how to provision the service:

http://www.brainlitter.com/2013/01/09/provisioning-the-work-management-service-application/

Comment: As indicated in the Edit, yes the list is really missing. I would also assume that it has to do with Work Management Service Provisioning, but there's not much to it and it was done by a senior team member. I do see that it mentions a people search crawl, which I don't know it we did it. I'm no longer at the client experiencing this problem but thx for the tip!